# libusb support to Yocto build for Freescale imx6 board

Tags: bluetooth, usb, libusb, yocto, bsp

I am currently working with creating an alternative BSP using Yocto to replace the existing BSP. I am new to Yocto and I need to know how I can add libusb support to Yocto to detect the bluetooth dongle when attached.

Regards,
Pavan

Answer (score 7):

You could use [OpenEmbedded Layer Index](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layers/) to search for recipes available in Yocto.  [libusb1 recipe](http://cgit.openembedded.org/cgit.cgi/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-support/libusb/libusb1_1.0.20.bb?h=master) is here.

Then, to add that recipe to your Image, in `/build/conf/local.conf`, add `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " libusb1 "`

Another option is to create `core-image-full-cmdline` for a console-only image with more full-featured Linux system
functionality installed.